# Accessing postgres using slick is not working

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have following environment scala2.11.8 / akka 2.4.8 / slick 3.1.1 / postgreSQL 9.6

I have done following configuration in application.conf

```
mydb {
  driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
  db {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
    driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    user="postgres"
    password="postgres"
    numThreads = 10
    connectionPool = disabled
    keepAliveConnection = true
  }
}
```

The DB access is done in class

```
package mib
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
class DBAccess {
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
  import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
  import slick.driver.PostgresDriver
  import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._  
  import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database

  println("creating database")
 val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[PostgresDriver] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("mydb")
 val db = dbConfig.db
 try{
 val accesspoints = TableQuery[mibPoint] 
  // SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='john'
  val q = for (a <- accesspoints) yield a.mib_id
  val dbAction = q.result
  val f: Future[Seq[String]] = db.run(dbAction)
  Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
  f.onSuccess { case s => println(s"Result: $s") }
  }
  catch
  {
    case _: Throwable =>println("got some exception")
  }
  finally 
    db.close
}

// this is a class that represents the table I've created in the database
  class mibPoint(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double,Double)](tag, "mib_non_info") {
    def mac_id = column[String]("mib_id",O.PrimaryKey)
    def lat = column[Double]("lat")
    def lng = column[Double]("lng")
    def * = (mib_id, lat,lng)
  }
```

This class is called from APP object as

```
object wmib extends App {    
  val mWBootStrapper =  new bootStrap
  mWBootStrapper.ReadProperties();
  val mdB  = new DBAccess 
}
```

However after running, I always get the output as "got some exception"
I have tried to enable logging using slf4j/logback but still i do not see much in the logs.
The above seems like very trivial and probably i am missing something obvious. 
Thanks in advance,
Vishal

I added the exception handling as suggested by sarvesh. That was cool and thank you.
However my problem vanished and there was no exception. 
What happened? 
Earlier in the day, I had attempted to access the DB using the java JDBC way.
i.e. just to check that there is nothing wrong with DB and DB access.
In the process, I downloaded and added the postgresDriver in the classpath. Earlier that was not the case. 
Since the driver was now in the path, the code just worked. 
Since I was not printing the exception, i was not realizing the error. 
I then removed the driver jar AND i got the following error.

```
01:44:08.224 [mydb.db-1] DEBUG slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement - Preparing statement: select "mib_id" from "mibpoint"
01:44:08.224 [mydb.db-1] DEBUG slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource - Driver org.postgresql.Driver not already registered; trying to load it
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at slick.util.ClassLoaderUtil$$anon$1.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.scala:12)
    at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource$$anonfun$init$2.apply(DriverDataSource.scala:60)
    at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource$$anonfun$init$2.apply(DriverDataSource.scala:58)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

Thanks to all for helping.
Vishal

Comment: The thrown exception and a stack trace might be helpful here.

Comment: first please replace this `case _: Throwable =>println("got some exception")` with `case ex: Throwable => ex.printStackTrace()` which will print the actual stack trace of error. Update your question with that information.

Comment: Can't help you until you post the stacktrace, but I have a minimal working example with mysql that shouldn't be very different from psql https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps

Comment: @vishal @Sarvesh Kumar Singh catching `Throwable` is certainly not a thing you want to do. In both Java nad Scala `OutOfMemory` exception extends `Throwable` so your appliaction may fail and you will catch it here. It's a very bad practice. Catch `Exception` at most.

Comment: @Michał He can move on to those details, once he learn the basics.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Sure thing, but still worth noticing :)

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same connection issues when first using Slick. I submitted this PR with details on how to connect up a local Postgres server.

https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1861#issuecomment-387616310.

But basically try edit your build.sbt and application.conf files:

[image: postgres setup for slick]

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you for sharing that github link. +1

Answer (score 2):

**The 2020 answer**:

You have to make sure of two things:

1. Add the driver to the `build.sbt`'s `libraryDependencies`: `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.5"`. That will cause `java.sql.DriverManager`'s method `getDrivers` (which is used by slick in class `DriverDataSource`) to find the driver `org.postgresql.Driver`
2. Make sure that the database url in `application.conf` is following the JDBC's full-url pattern, as described in the source code: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/42d787b4950fe876569b5fd68e98c4e0379ac83c/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/DatabaseUrlDataSource.scala#L9. For example: `postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres`.

My full configuration is:

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...,
      "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.5"
    )
```

**application.conf**

```
slick-postgres {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
  db {
    dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
    properties = {
      driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
      url = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the exception handling as suggested by sarvesh. That was cool and thank you. However my problem vanished and there was no exception. What happened? Earlier in the day, I had attempted to access the DB using the java JDBC way. i.e. just to check that there is nothing wrong with DB and DB access. In the process, I downloaded and added the postgresDriver in the classpath. Earlier that was not the case. Since the driver was now in the path, the code just worked. Since I was not printing the exception, i was not realizing the error. I then removed the driver jar AND i got the following error.

```
01:44:08.224 [mydb.db-1] DEBUG slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement - Preparing statement: select "mib_id" from "mibpoint"
01:44:08.224 [mydb.db-1] DEBUG slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource - Driver org.postgresql.Driver not already registered; trying to load it
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at slick.util.ClassLoaderUtil$$anon$1.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.scala:12)
    at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource$$anonfun$init$2.apply(DriverDataSource.scala:60)
    at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource$$anonfun$init$2.apply(DriverDataSource.scala:58)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

Thanks to all for helping. Vishal

Answer (score 0):

```
mydb {
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  properties = {
    driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
    url = "postgres://postgresql:postgresql@localhost:5432/mydb"
  }
}
```

Or.. you can try something like,

```
mydb = {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
    user = "postgres"
    password = "postgres"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the Postgres Driver on the classpath:

Try adding `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"` to your libraryDependencies.